# Cannot implicitly convert type '(string, int USD) to 'string'

Tags: c#

I've struggled how to fix the issue where I want to put an array's variable inside another array's empty variable but formatted while using a FOR LOOP. The error I et is

> Cannot implicitly convert type '(string, string) to 'string'

Can I not implement it this way or am I doing something dumb?

For background, I'm trying to format the strings in the `string[]` arrays so it comes out like this :

```
----------------------------------------------------
9 USD: [Base coins: 450] [Added coins: 0] 
[Total coins: 450]

12 USD: [Base coins: 600] [Added coins: 0] 
[Total coins: 600]

----------------------------------------------------
```

But formatted so it doesn't have that weird spacing due to longer/shorter numbers by using the Alignment component:

```
("{0, -5}", string[0]); //This is not the full code, just a snippet
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

(until 20 minutes later after posting this I will probably realize the stupid problem)

```
    int USD = 3;
    int coins = 150;
    int extraCoins = 0;

    string[] names = { "USD", "Base coins", "Added coins", "Total coins" };
    char[] specialCharacters = { '[', ']', ':' };   // Used to indent strings

    string[] numbers = new string[iterations + 1];  // Iterations is a global variable set to 10

    for (int i = 1; i < numbers.Length; i++)
    {
        //numbers[i] = ($"{USD * i} USD: [Base coins: {_coins * i}] [Added coins: {extraCoins * i}] \n[Total coins: {(_coins * i) + (extraCoins * i)}]");
        numbers[i] = ("{0,-5}", string[0]); //THIS IS THE PROBLEM >:(
    }

    return numbers;
```

Comment: _numbers[i] = $"{USD,-5}";_  See [Interpolated Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)

Comment: Assuming c# 7 or higher, `("{0,-5}", string[0]);` is a value tuple containing a couple of string properties. You need to use an interpolated string, like Steve wrote.

Comment: I didn't realize I could use interpolated strings like that so that makes my job 10x easier, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you either need to use string interpolation or String.Format

```
 numbers[i] = $"{string[0],-5}";
```

or

```
 number[i] = String.Format("{0,5}",string[0]);
```